# How can I set focus for mat-input inside the mat-radio

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular7, mat-input

I am trying to set the focus (the cursor to blink) on the input box on the click on the custom radio button. But it is not happening.I have stackblitz demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-binding-gaogfr?file=app/app.component.html).

so far I have tried.

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selection" #radioGroup="matRadioGroup">
  <mat-radio-button value="option 1">option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="option 2">option 2</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="option 3">option 3</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="option 4">option 4</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="customOption" (click)="onBlur()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput id="input" [(ngModel)]="customOption" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

in component

```
onBlur() {
      document.getElementById('input').focus();
   }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show the code you think should work.

Comment: I have updated the question with the my trial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it sets focus to the input element before the action of selecting the radio button completes so, once it does complete, it immediately switches the focus to the radio button.

One solution is to change

`document.getElementById('input').focus();`

to

`setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('input').focus());`

so that it waits a moment before setting focus to the input element.